# Prestashop 1.7 : How to create a basic custom admin controller?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I was able to create a menu tab in the back office but when I click on it, I get 
`Page not found.
The controller is missing or invalid.`

Here's the code for my controller -

```
<?php

class AdminModuleNameConvert extends ModuleAdminController {


    public function __construct()   {
        $this->bootstrap = true;
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Using the solution provided by ethercreation, I get the controller to load, but it shows me

[image: Invalid security token]

Answer (score 2):

Try width :

In your module : `modulenameconverter`

```php
class modulenameconverter extends Module
{
    public function __construct(Context $context = null)
    {
        $this->name = 'modulenameconverter';
        $this->version = '1';
        $this->bootstrap = true;
        $this->author = 'Stackoverflow';
        $this->displayName = $this->l('modulenameconverter');
        $this->description = $this->l('Module name converter');
        
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function install()
    {
        $tab = new Tab();
        $tab->class_name = 'Adminmodulenameconverter';
        $tab->module = 'modulenameconverter';
        $tab->name[1] = 'modulenameconverter';
        $tab->id_parent = 2;
        $tab->active = 1;
        if (!$tab->save()) {
            return false;
        }
        return parent::install();
    }

    public function uninstall()
    {
        $id_tab = (int)Tab::getIdFromClassName('Adminmodulenameconverter');
        $tab = new Tab($id_tab);

        if (Validate::isLoadedObject($tab)) {
            if (!$tab->delete()) {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        return parent::uninstall();
    }
}
```

In `module/controllers/admin/AdminModulenameconverterController.php`

```php
class AdminNameconverterController extends ModuleAdminController
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->bootstrap = true;
        $this->id_lang = $this->context->language->id;
        $this->default_form_language = $this->context->language->id;
    }

    public function initContent()
    {
        parent::initContent();
    } 
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I get the same error - 'Page not found. The controller AdminmodulenameController is missing or invalid.'. I am using modulename and not modulenameconverter. Can you please specify which class names need to be in lowercase and which ones need to be in uppercase. Thanks!

Comment: Turns out my module class was named incorrectly. Thanks!

Comment: Ok closed question please :)

Comment: Please help with the error. I have updated the question. I get a security warning before I can get the controller to load.

Answer (score -2):

I was having the exact same issue and it appears that I was not configuring the tab parameters correctly... I was trying to pass an array for the "$this->module" parameter so Prestashop could not find the module because in the database, the module linked to the tab was equal to ""...

So my best advice in this case is to always check your database fields to see if they are correctly filled.

To conclude : It's always the silliest issues that makes the biggest headaches... -_-'